# "No host pages were found. Launch anyway?" Error

Tags: eclipse, html, gwt, maven, playn

I've installed all the plugins and imported the sample projects.

When I try to run it as "Web Application" I get a message box saying "Could not find any host pages in project playn-showcase-html".

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance guys,

Paolo

Comment: what sample project are you using? and if possible give links for that.

Comment: playn showcase from playn-samples git